# building boost on Cygwin - b2.exe does not work

Tags: boost, build, cygwin

I did [`git clone --recursive https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git`](https://github.com/boostorg/wiki/wiki/Getting-Started%3A-Overview)

I ran `./bootstrap.sh` and it produces a `./b2.exe`.

But `./b2.exe --help` does nothing

I'm using Cygwin

In MSYS2, it works fine.

```
$ cygcheck ./b2.exe
C:\work\misc\boost\boost-repo\b2.exe
  C:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll
    C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-1-0.dll
      C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
      C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-1-0.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-0.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-1-0.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-file-l1-1-0.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-namedpipe-l1-1-0.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-0.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-1-0.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-1-0.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-0.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-console-l1-2-0.dll
  C:\cygwin64\usr\local\bin\cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll
  C:\cygwin64\usr\local\bin\cygstdc++-6.dll
  C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
    C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
    C:\Windows\system32\SECHOST.dll
      C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
        C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-1-0.dll
```

Comment: have you run `./bootstrap.sh` before `./b2` ?

Comment: what is the output of ` cygcheck ./b2.exe` ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your TourtuoiseGit installation is contaminating the PATH
On my system I see:

```
$ cygcheck  ./b2.exe
C:\cygwin64\pub\tmp\boost\b2.exe
  C:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-1-0.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll
      ...
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll
  C:\cygwin64\bin\cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll
  C:\cygwin64\bin\cygstdc++-6.dll
  C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\SECHOST.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
        C:\WINDOWS\system32\api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-1-0.dll
```

I suggest to set system variable CYGWIN_NOWINPATH not empty as mentioned on `/etc/profile`

after that you should have a PATH very clean with few elements

```
$ echo $CYGWIN_NOWINPATH
YES

$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/lapack
```

on my system the b2 output is:

```
$ ./b2 --help
B2 4.9-git

Project-specific help:

  Project has jamfile at Jamroot

Usage:

  b2 [options] [properties] [install|stage]

  Builds and installs Boost.

Targets and Related Options:
...
```

However be aware that boost is not really Cygwin aware and will require code modification. After installing `cmake`, `make`, a bunch of `devel` packages and changing some cmake settings you could arrive at

```
--   i18n (required): /usr/lib/libicui18n.dll.a
--   uc (required): /usr/lib/libicuuc.dll.a
-- Boost.Stacktrace: noop ON, backtrace OFF, addr2line ON, basic ON, windbg ON, windbg_cached ON
-- Boost.Thread: threading API is pthread
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at libs/context/CMakeLists.txt:197 (add_library):
  Cannot find source file:

    src/asm/make_x86_64_sysv_pe_gas.S

...
```

and I see only

```
$ find ../boost -name make*pe*.S
../boost/libs/context/src/asm/make_i386_ms_pe_clang_gas.S
../boost/libs/context/src/asm/make_x86_64_ms_pe_clang_gas.S
```

so or it needs, maybe but unlikely, Clang for the build or you need to teach boost to talk the Unix/Cygwin way and not a MS way.
Not easy task and it is likely one of the reason that today the Cygwin package is without a maintainer; see
https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/boost-src.html

Comment: I switched to WSL; I expect there is no more reason for Cygwin to exist.

Comment: except when your corporation does not allow the use of WSL ;-) or you need more interaction with Windows file to manipulate.